# Android always on Hotword detection Without PocketSphinx

Tags: java, android

How to create always on hotword detection **without** PocketSphinx (only using android api methods).

My app is already listed as assist app.
Implemented `VoiceInteractionService,VoiceInteractionSessionService,VoiceInteractionSession,AlwaysOnHotwordDetector.Callback`.

On `onReady` is called

```
createAlwaysOnHotwordDetector("Hello", Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US"), new xDetector());
```

And `onAvailabilityChanged` always returns -1 (`STATE_KEYPHRASE_UNSUPPORTED`).

`mParseError` has value `no enrollment applications found`.

And `mKeyphrasePackageMap` is empty.

And

```
List<ResolveInfo> ris = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(new Intent("com.android.intent.action.MANAGE_VOICE_KEYPHRASES"), PackageManager.MATCH_ALL);
```

is empty.

How to solve this?

Comment: Is there anybody here?

Comment: If you're still on this (or remember - or got it to work --> did you?), were you able to put MainInteractionSession working? And another question.... How did you get onReady() to work at all?? I've been trying and I can't in any way and I don't know why. App is as system app, btw. I'm following this from here: http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/tests/VoiceInteraction/.